# How to get user entered data from an html form and add to a JSON string to be sent in a POST request using JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, slack-api

I am trying to get data from an html form added into a JSON string to be sent as payload in a POST request.

My HTML code so far:

```
<form id="myForm">
      <label class="fnameLabel1" for="fname">FULL NAME</label>
      <input class="fname1" type="text" id="fname" name="fullname" placeholder="" required>

      <label class="emailLabel1" for="email">EMAIL</label>
      <input class="email1" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="" required>

      <input  class="submit1" type="submit" value="Book Now" id="submit1">

    </form>
```

So my real issue is, how do I get whatever is entered in those input fields here on submit:

```
  <script>  
  $('submit1').click(function () {


     var url = "http://www.my_api_url.com/apiurl";

     var payload = {
       "attachments": [{
         "fallback": "testing:",
         "pretext": "testing:",
         "color": "#00008b",
         "fields": [{
           "title": "Name",
           "value": **NAME ENTERED IN FORM**,
           "title": "Email",
           "value": **EMAIL ENTERED IN FORM**,
           "short": true
         }]
       }]
     }

     $.post(url.JSON.stringify(payload), function (data) {
       $('#result').text(data);
     })
  })
</script>
```

I am not sure if I am doing this right, or close to being right. my goal is when a user enters in their data and clicks submit. that data is sent to the desired api. I do not know how I can add that data into the JSON though, or if there are any better ways to achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 0):

The way you create your JS-Object looks clean (I'm not sure if you need the square brackets though). How you parse it too. To get the value of the input field my simplest pure js solution would be:

```
    document.getElementById("fname").value;
```

Source: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript.php

The post request should probably look like this:

```
   $.post(url, JSON.stringify(payload), function (data) { $.('#result').text(data); })
```

Source: https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-send-receive-json-data-from-the-server.cfm

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/